# Extracting first word from a string that has more than three letters

Tags: r, string

so I have a string:

"I am a dentist in a health organization."

I would like to extract the first word that contains more than three letters and put it into a new column in a datatable, i.e. in this case "dentist". I suppose I have to use strsplit, but I have no idea on how to proceed.

Any help is appreciated

Regards,
Antje

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to ask a question, and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Try this easy solution:

```
string<-"I am a dentist in a health organization."
words<-unlist(strsplit(string," "))
words[which.max(nchar(words)>3)]
[1] "dentist"
```

To apply this solution to a dataframe adding a column:

```
df<-data.frame(string=c("I am a dentist in a health organization.","a dentist in a health organization.","health organization."))

f<-function(string,n)
{
  words<-unlist(strsplit(string," "))
  return(words[which.max(nchar(words)>n)])

}

df$word<-unlist(lapply(as.character(df$string),f,n=3))

df
                                    string    word
1 I am a dentist in a health organization. dentist
2      a dentist in a health organization. dentist
3                     health organization.  health
```

Answer (score 1):

Match, from the beginning, `"^"`, the shortest sequence of characters, `".*?"`, followed by a word of 4 or more characters, `"\\b(\\w{4,}\\b"` followed by the remaining text, `".*"`, and replace all that with the first (and only) capture group (i.e. the match to the part of the regular expression with parentheses).

```
# input data frame
DF <- data.frame(x = c("I am a dentist in a health organization.", 
  "I am a dentist in a health organization."))

pat <- "^.*?\\b(\\w{4,})\\b.*"
transform(DF, longword = sub(pat, "\\1", x))
```

giving:

```
                                         x longword
1 I am a dentist in a health organization.  dentist
2 I am a dentist in a health organization.  dentist
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `\w{4,}` matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
2. `{4,}` Quantifier — Matches between 4 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
3. Non-capturing group `(?:\\w+)?`
4. `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
5. `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

`strng <- "I am a dentist in a health organization."`

`stringr::str_extract(strng,"\\w{4,}(?:\\w+)?")`

Result

`[1] "dentist"`